# В чем разница между open beta и продакшн?

Tags: android, google-play, playmarket

Есть несколько каналов `internal test, close alpha, open beta, production`

С internal test понятно, с close alpha тоже (доступно только для того кому можно), но вот `open beta` она ведь так же в общем доступе на `PlayMarket` как и `production`.

Это считается общирным финальным тестом по сути, перед продакшн. Но технически чем эти версии отличаются кроме названия канала `open beta и production`?

Я так понимаю, что только тем, что пользователь(тестер) не может оставить отзыв... Чтоб не портить репутацию приложения которое еще (условно) не готово.

Это и все или еще что то нужно знать о разнице этих каналов?

Comment: Вероятно, бета ставится только тем, кто сознательно решил участвовать в бете?

Comment: пользователи могут оставлять отзывы, которые можно прочитать в "Отзывы тестировщиков", которые могут быть очень ценными (все устройства не охватить)

Answer (score 0):

Open beta это версия, которая уже открыта для загрузки всеми желающими, но в то же время пока ещё по каким-то причинам остаётся тестовой. Разумеется, что последнее предполагает сознательное решение использования беты со всеми вытекающими.

Продакшн версия, это уже официально полностью готовый вариант приложения.